# Equivalent of \\tsclient for VMWare vSphere Console

Tags: vmware-vsphere

What is the \\tsclient equivalent to access the host hard drive for VMWare vSphere consoles?

That is, a network drive shortcut from the vm to the connecting machine.

The option to connect a USB drive is useful, but not as useful as the rdp tsclient shortcut is.

Comment: What data are you trying to access - do you mean from the client you're connecting from, or from the host?  And you're looking to access this data from a VM, correct?  Please clarify what data you need, where it is, and where you need to get it.  There's no "equivalent", but there are certainly options.

Comment: Trying to connect from the VM to the connecting machine.

Comment: Hopefully this is not a production vmware vsphere deploy of any value.  Because if it is it will be screwed up shortlyl.

Comment: Nah, development environments. So screwing it is more of an inevitability.

Comment: The only reason a direct network share is not an option is because the domain trust relationship is bollo...

Comment: so the vcenter is a member of domain A but the guests are members of domain B but you want to access the local drives on the vcenter server, is that correct?

Comment: vccenter is hosted on domain 'DEV' and guests are members of 'PROD', wanted to access local drives of guest from domain 'DEV'.

Comment: Mostly I was wanting to know if there was a generic shortcut for any given guest rather than having to know your own IP address. It's not particularly onerous, but it did surprise me that no shortcut was coded into the VMWare client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't.  You need to create a regular file share.